# Plymouth manager boot splash screen only during shutdown and not during Restart

Tags: plymouth

Well i tried to customize the bootsplash screen from Plymouth manager and somehow the selected bootsplash themes only shows up during shutdown but when restart and at the grub it shows a Dark screen and not that bootsplash screen i selected.

Plz help

Regard

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the driver is not yet loaded when it is supposed to run. If so, this may fix that:

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

This wasn't enough for Ubuntustudio 13.10. In addition to the commands above:

In `/etc/default/grub` change `GFXMODE=1280x1024` (my screen resolution)

Also, in `/etc/grub.d/00_header` insert `set gfxpayload=keep` on the line after `set gfxmode={GRUB_GFXMODE}`

Save each file and then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This wasn't enough for Ubuntustudio 13.10. In addition to the commands above:

Comment: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141295)